# Nginx: Block Content URL (.MP4 or .PNG) based on LUA Redis

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I would like to block access to certain content (such as video and image) if the user is not in the session.
And to check if it is authenticated I use it on my backend (through redis): hset users token123 on

Example URL request: ./content/s04-40dm4-de2020.mp4?token=token123

I would like to check through the lua-resty-redis module if "token123" is "on", if nginx is not going to "block" the request, if it will be allowed normally.
I don't know how to do this without losing a lot of performance, I'm currently mixing the redis module with this:

```
content_by_lua '
    ... (Check in lua-resty-redis equals "on")
     local file = "/ path ..."
     local f = io.open (file, "rb")
     local content = f: read ("* all")
     f: close ()
     ngx.print (content)
';
```

Is there a way to only block if you are not authenticated and do not do this above?
Note: Location in nginx: "location ~* ^.+.(jpeg|gif|png|jpg|mp4|...etc)"

Comment: Is there any way of checking Cookies? Does the user have a Session-Cookie if logged in?

Comment: R: Unfortunately not, the content is usually displayed via third party player like VLC, ExoPlayer (android) etc.
Basically they use this URL, eg: /user/pass/watch/id1, where they will be redirected to /video/example.mp4?token=gerado.
I am currently serving .mp4 with PHP (fopen), this is terrible for performance.

Comment: My problem was solved thanks to you.
If you want, you can post a question instead of a comment that I will mark as resolved.
Basically I'm using "auth_request /verify" where "/verify" forwards a request with the header: "X-Original-Url" that contains $ request_uri, after that I check if the? Token = is valid, if I return it with the header "Valid" to "True", and get the return (response) using auth_request_set   $http_valid $upstream_http_valid;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NGINX auth_request to handle the verification of the token.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html#auth_request

```
location /contents/ {
    auth_request /auth;
    ...
}

location = /auth {

    #Validate your token here. You can use proxy request, njs js_content or lua.

    proxy_pass ...
    proxy_pass_request_body off;
    proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
    proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
}
```